# Can the username autocomplete be keyboard accessible?

Tags: support, chat

Both in chat and when posting comments, an autocomplete box shows up for users.
[image: Autocomplete users]
Can this be made so you can select the user using the up arrow key, then the right/left arrows? So, let's take the example above. I push the up arrow to highlight "memilanuk", then the right arrow key to highlight "mankoff", and press Enter to select "mankoff". I hope this makes sense...but could it be implemented? I find it somewhat annoying that I have to use the mouse to select the name.

Comment: @balpha Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use the mouse. You can use the Tab key to cycle to the list (or Shift-Tab to cycle backwards).